# Download file size is unknown although file size is present in header

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, download, zip

I am doing the follwoing on a web page: A click on an element sends a set of data (attached to the element) to my server which will then generate a custom zip-file:

```
$.post(urlprefix + 'makeZip.php', params, function(data){
    window.location = urlprefix + 'getZip.php?file=' + data; //get file
}).error(handleAJAXError);
```

`makeZip.php` works just fine and returns the name of the (temporary) zip file that the client should then download. As I want to keep my server clean I route the file through another script called `getZip.php` which does the following:

```
/* RETURN REQUESTED FILE AND DELETE FROM SERVER*/
$filename = $_GET['file'];
/* TRANSFER FILE CONTENTS */
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="customDownload.zip"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
/* REMOVE FILE FROM SERVER */
unlink($filename);
```

All browsers will download the file successfully, yet I am facing one problem: the files can get rather big (up to 200MB) so I thought it would be nice to have an estimate of how long the download's going to take. That's why I am sending the `Content-Length` header (the specified filesize is correct). Yet, all browsers I tested this is are telling me the filesize is unknown (which might lead to the user skipping the download).

Is this some kind of problem with my header information? Is it a client-side problem? Should I use another approach to getting the client to download the file?

Comment: Could you check with fiddler or similar that the browser doesn't do a `HEAD` request first to get the file size? If so, you may need to return the same information when you get that request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the client shows "unknown filesize" in the dialog when downloading a file provided via readfile, you'd better check if `mod_deflate`, `mod_gzip`, `mod_something-that-shrinks-http` is installed on your server, and put an exception for given download.

More info **[here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=728395)**

**EDIT** by m90:

In my particular case (running Apache) I turned shrinking off by using:

```
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
```

Filesize headers are sent and received correctly now in all browsers

Comment: Seems to be the cause of the problem: I used `@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);` in my script (cannot do that server-wide) and it's working just fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @m90 - it is better to add your own answer, than substantially change someone else's. It is then clearer who has written what without having to check previous versions `:)`.

Comment: @halfer Do you really think this is an *substantial* change? In my eyes I just specified the (turning out to be true) assumptions made?

Comment: @m90 - fair point, but bear in mind that since StackOverflow data is available via XML (and APIs I think), authorship metadata is confused if you add _your own_ answer inside someone else's. It is much better to add your own answer, and still give the original person the tick, imo.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out for a while trying to get Apache to not compress in certain situations. I tried updating my conf file with `SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI (download) no-gzip dont-vary` to try and get it to ignore URIs with the word download in them but a rewrite cond was screwing it up and the only way I could get around it was to use `index.php` in the URL. This post deserves way more upvotes.